# Adding headers to an HTTP POST/GET Request with TornadoFX

Tags: rest, kotlin, desktop-application, tornadofx

I've been going through [this](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/part2/JSON%20and%20REST.html) tutorial on TornadoFX which describes how to add parameters to an HTTP REST request. My API requires additional headers for certain calls. I am unable to find how to send them along, and the only methods I see for headers are regarding returning headers from the response I get back.

Answer (score 2):

You can alter the request before it is fired by supplying a lambda as the last parameter:

```
api.post(path, payload) { request ->
    request.addHeader("key", "value")
}
```

Comment: I've found it's also possible to get rid of the "request ->" part and just refer to request by "it'. Also, is there a way to encode the params as a body rather than as a url?